# Insert open braces as part of String using jooq

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am trying to insert a curly braces as part of String with jooq.

```
Example: insert into test values ({'open braces{randomtext} present'})
```

to overcome the problem of first braces (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4408) I tried

```
sql = insert into test values ({{'open braces not present'}}) it worked.
```

But I am not able to execute statement like 
`insert into test values ({{'open braces { yes } present'}})`. throws ArrayOutofBoundException.

Comment: Are you sure you have those curly braces at the right spot, i.e. outside of the string literal?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting what u are aiming at, but if I understand jooq correctly its there to escape curly braces, so shouldn't your insert be like: insert into test values ('open braces {{ yes }} present')